# How to draw a line behind a surface plot using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a line inside a torus which I have drawn with a surface plot. The line should not be visible inside the torus - like the inner side of the torus, which can only be seen at the "ends" of the torus (I cut-off one half of the torus). The line I have drawn is however visible everywhere (as you can see in the plot).

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# theta: poloidal angle | phi: toroidal angle
# note: only plot half a torus, thus phi=0...pi
theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 200)
phi   = np.linspace(0, 1.*np.pi, 200)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)

# major and minor radius
R0, a = 3., 1.

# torus parametrization
x_torus = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
y_torus = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
z_torus = a * np.sin(theta)

# parametrization for a circular line at theta=0
x_circle = (R0-a/2. + a*np.cos(.0)) * np.cos(phi)
y_circle = (R0-a/2. + a*np.cos(.0)) * np.sin(phi)
z_circle = a * np.sin(.0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# plot half of a circular line
ax1.plot3D( x_circle, y_circle, z_circle )

# plot half of torus
ax1.plot_surface( x_torus, y_torus, z_torus )

ax1.view_init(elev=15, azim=270)
ax1.set_xlim( -3, 3)
ax1.set_ylim( -3, 3)
ax1.set_zlim( -3, 3)
ax1.set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

I thought simply plotting the line *first* should solve my problem, but it doesn't. Any suggestion or help how to change the behaviour of the line is greatly appreciated.

```
numpy.__version__     : 1.12.1
matplotlib.__version__: 2.0.0
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699494/how-to-obscure-a-line-behind-a-surface-plot-in-matplotlib/41706895#41706895

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks, looks like there is no easy solution to my problem, as it is slightly more complicated (due to being inside of a torus and not just behind an object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option one - use Mayavi

The easier way to do this would be with the [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html) library. This is pretty similar to `matplotlib`, the only meaningful differences for this script are that the `x`, `y`, and `z` arrays passed to `plot3d` to plot the line should be 1d and the `view` is set a bit differently (depending on whether it is set before or after plotting, and the alt/az are measured from different reference).

```py
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
from mayavi.api import OffScreenEngine
mlab.options.offscreen = True

# theta: poloidal angle | phi: toroidal angle
# note: only plot half a torus, thus phi=0...pi
theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 200)
phi   = np.linspace(0, 1.*np.pi, 200)

# major and minor radius
R0, a = 3., 1.

x_circle = R0 * np.cos(phi)
y_circle = R0 * np.sin(phi)
z_circle = np.zeros_like(x_circle)

# Delay meshgrid until after circle construction
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
x_torus = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
y_torus = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
z_torus = a * np.sin(theta)

mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), size=(1000,1000))
mlab.view(azimuth=90, elevation=105)

mlab.plot3d(x_circle, y_circle, z_circle)
mlab.mesh(x_torus, y_torus, z_torus, color=(0.0, 0.5, 1.0))
mlab.savefig("./example.png")
# mlab.show() has issues with rendering for some setups
```

[image: Toroid with line using mayavi]

### Option two - use matplotlib (with some added unpleasantness)

If you can't use `mayavi` it is possible to accomplish this with `matplotlib`, it's just... unpleasant. The approach is based on the idea of [creating transparent 'bridges' between surfaces and then plotting them together as one surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531752/display-the-maximum-surface-in-matplotlib/28608098#28608098). This is not trivial for more complex combinations, but here is an example for the toroid with a line which is fairly straightforward

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 200)
phi   = np.linspace(0, 1.*np.pi, 200)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)

# major and minor radius
R0, a = 3., 1.
lw = 0.05 # Width of line

# Cue the unpleasantness - the circle must also be drawn as a toroid
x_circle = (R0 + lw*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
y_circle = (R0 + lw*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
z_circle = lw * np.sin(theta)
c_circle = np.full_like(x_circle, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), dtype=(float,4))

# Delay meshgrid until after circle construction
x_torus = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
y_torus = (R0 + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
z_torus = a * np.sin(theta)
c_torus = np.full_like(x_torus, (0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0), dtype=(float, 4))

# Create the bridge, filled with transparency
x_bridge = np.vstack([x_circle[-1,:],x_torus[0,:]])
y_bridge = np.vstack([y_circle[-1,:],y_torus[0,:]])
z_bridge = np.vstack([z_circle[-1,:],z_torus[0,:]])
c_bridge = np.full_like(z_bridge, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), dtype=(float, 4))

# Join the circle and torus with the transparent bridge
X = np.vstack([x_circle, x_bridge, x_torus])
Y = np.vstack([y_circle, y_bridge, y_torus])
Z = np.vstack([z_circle, z_bridge, z_torus])
C = np.vstack([c_circle, c_bridge, c_torus])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=C, linewidth=0)
ax.view_init(elev=15, azim=270)
ax.set_xlim( -3, 3)
ax.set_ylim( -3, 3)
ax.set_zlim( -3, 3)
ax.set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

[image: Toroid with line using mpl]

**Note** in both cases I changed the circle to match the major radius of the toroid for demonstration simplicity, it can easily be altered as needed.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about the Mayavi library, thanks! Also also thanks a lot for the "unpleasant" matplotlib solution^^

Comment: @Alf No problem, I recently encountered a similar issue for which the `matplotlib` solution proved insufficient - hence `mayavi`. I hope one of the two works for your uses

Comment: @Alf If this answered your question don't forget to accept it so it is marked as such for future users

Comment: Sorry for my late reply,  but I think there is a typo in your (very useful!) mayavi code: for `x_circle` and `y_circle` it should rather be `a/2` or some other value different from `a` to get a line centered in the torus like in the plot you generated and included in your response.

Comment: @Alf You are correct, that was a typo - based on the definitions of major and minor toroidal radius [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry) it should be `x_circle = R0 * np.cos(phi)` and `y_circle = R0 * np.sin(phi)`. This of course assumes a parameterization wherein major radius is the "distance from the center of the tube to the center of the torus".