# How to restrict domain in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I would like to do a surface plot of a function f(x,y) that is defined for any integers x and y. The caveat is that I want to restrict the domain of (x,y) to a convex but non-rectangular region. (For example, I want to restrict to x>=0, y>=0, x+y<=b for some known integer b.)

I have been able to follow the [matplotlib surface plotting examples](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), however all of these examples impose a rectangular domain.  If you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this, they would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is required for a matplotlib 3D `plot_surface` is a rectilinear grid, not a rectangular domain, see e.g. the surface of a sphere, which is not rectangular at all. I see two options, use a grid which only contains the desired values (x+y<=b) or mask a rectangular grid by the condition.

Comment: Oh, sorry, if x and y can only be integers, you cannot squeeze the grid, hence only the second option is possible. But, a third option would be to plot a `trisurf` plot, which does not have this restriction at all.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, would you mind elaborating on "or mask a rectangular grid by the condition."  I'm not quite sure I know what that means. Thank you!

Comment: numpy provides masked arrays. Seems like [this is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577248/how-to-make-a-3d-matlibplot-not-show-masked-values) though. So, it now depends on whether you need a colormap or not, using `nan`s would prevent a colormap from being used. Should we close this as duplicate?