# matplotlib surface plot limited by the boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any kind of chance to "cut" the surface plot (x,y,z) made by use of the matplotlib by some well defined boundaries, so that I can draw any kind of shape in 3D. Now I can do that but x,y are 2D arrays (meshgrid) and the shape is always rectangular.

Example:

Here, the plate has a base-shape of rectangular (2d-array are used). The z coordinates are derived by some function f=f(x,y).
[image]

What I would like achieve is shown in the picture below (made by hand ;)). One idea is to turn-off a single cell. But how to make the cells transparent?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example (visual would be nice) of exactly what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

What you'd like is to *mask* some regions in the surface. Unfortunately, matplotlib does not support masked arrays yet for `plot_surface`, but you could circumvent it by using `np.nan` for those masked regions. 
It is also detailed in [plotting-a-masked-surface-plot-using-python-numpy-and-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020160/plotting-a-masked-surface-plot-using-python-numpy-and-matplotlib).