# How can I plot this kind of picture using Matplotlib or Mayavi?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, 3d, mayavi

I have three 2d arrays: *X,Y,Z*, which contain irregular 3d points coordinate,respectively.And another 2d array *data*, which contains the values on those points.
What I want to do is to display this data in 3d space , with 0 value part masked out.Much like this one:

[image]

In *matlab*, I can use function *fill3* to achieve this, but how can I plot the same kind of picture in *matplotlib* or *mayavi* ? I have tried to use *mask array ,plot_surface and colorface* together, as the example here:
[Plotting a masked surface plot using python, numpy and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020160/plotting-a-masked-surface-plot-using-python-numpy-and-matplotlib)

and it worked, the result is the link below:

[image]
but that is **really really slow, and will cost too much time**. Is there a better way?

Comment: The coordinate array are irregular distribution ! e.g.:
X=[0.1,0.2,5,-1,-2]  Y=[1,2,1.4,0,-5]  Z=[10,15,9,20,13]

Comment: My OCD forces me to hate with all my strength those non-perpendicular looking axis in matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, today I find out an alternative way to solve the problem. Except using plot_surface, I choose to use scatter3D,
the core code is some what like this
`aa=np.shape(X)[0]
        bb=np.shape(X)[1]
        x=X.reshape(aa*bb)
        y=Y.reshape(aa*bb)
        z=Z.reshape(aa*bb)
        data=data.reshape(aa*bb)
        x1=[]
        y1=[]
        z1=[]
        da1=[]
        for i in range(aa*bb):
            if data[i]>0:
                x1.append(x[i])
                y1.append(y[i])
                z1.append(z[i])
                da1.append(data[i])
        my_cmap=cm.jet
        my_cmap.set_over('c')
        my_cmap.set_under('m')
        N=da1/max(da1)
        fig=plt.figure()
        ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
        ax.scatter3D(x1,y1,z1,s=6,alpha=0.8,marker=',',facecolors=my_cmap(N),lw=0)`

and the result is like this:

[image]

this doesn't really solve the problem, but it is a nice substitution.
I'll keep waiting for more answers.